# OpenCV; Read Camera on macOS; TypeError

Tags: python, opencv

I try to run a camera reading code in macOS. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import os

os.system("clear")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3 , 640) 
cap.set(4 , 480) 

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()

    for barcode in decode(img):
    
        print(barcode.data)
    
        print(barcode.rect)
    
        x = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        print(x)

    cv2.imshow('Result', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

This is current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Pyzbar Lesson 2.py", line 21, in <module>
    for barcode in decode(img):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 207, in decode
    pixels, width, height = _pixel_data(image)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 173, in _pixel_data
    pixels, width, height = image
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Please, share if I miss anything or other error in the code.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you not checking `if not success: break`? where did you learn to use VideoCapture? those `set` calls are bad.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I learned it on a tutorial on yt. I've been scouring through multiple ones to see if there were any solutions or if I missed anything. As for '''if not success: break''' , I added that into the program. Thanks for your insight

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine on my Windows machine (after changing 'clear' to 'cls' of course).

You're getting a `Type Error` because decode is trying to operate on a `None` type. In line 21 you call `for barcode in decode(img)`. Here it is `img` that is 'None` and since decode cannot handle 'None' you get the error.

I suspect that your hardware is not cooperating properly. This could be due to your camera access preferences. You can use the `cap.isOpen()` and `cap.isValid()` checks to add an additional layer of trouble shooting.

Comment: This is not the code that gave you an error. I needed to see decode.py between lines 10 to 21.

Comment: @Jaeger I figured that first part out: if the camera isn't working, the '''img''' will be '''None''' as there would be no image to show. I tried the code with just a png and a jpg: it works perfectly. As for the other part, I think we can agree that the hardware is not cooperating properly. I'm not sure why. I've tried to used '''cap.isOpened()''' and '''cap.isValid()''': the first one returns '''True''' while the last one gives me an error saying there's no attribute. Either way, I'm still having trouble opening the camera. Thank you for help though

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY FOUND THE ANSWER
Apparently, for some macOS users, having 'cap.set()' in your code would give you errors. But after removing it, it works perfectly

'''

```
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import os

os.system("clear")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if not success:
        break

    for barcode in decode(img):

        print(barcode.data)

        print(barcode.rect)

        x = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        print(x)

    cv2.imshow('Result', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

'''